# I'm trying to test a string in java to see if it contains a digit

Tags: java, string, char

Hi can someone give some guidance. I'm trying to test a string to see if it has a digit and set a variable to true or false depending on the out come. This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    boolean hasDigit = false;
    String passCode = "abc";
    int valid = 0;

    if (Character.isdigit(passCode)) {
        hasDigit = true;
    } else {
        hasDigit = false;
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through your string and test each character individually. Break the loop once you find a digit character:

```
boolean hasDigit = false;
String passCode = "abc";
for (int i = 0; i < passCode.length(); i++) {
    if(Character.isDigit(passCode.charAt(i))) {
        hasDigit = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex:

```
if (passCode.matches(".*[0-9]+.*")) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution would be to write a **regex** test to see whether string has any digits between [0-9]. This will definitely give you desired outcome. Also you can easily update your **regex** to check for other conditions in string provided.

Answer (score -1):

Use Character.isDigit() function in loop to check each character in string whether character is digit or not

public class TestNumber {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String s="abc1";

            boolean isDigit = false;


            for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
            {
                if(Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))){


                        isDigit=true;
                        break;
                }

                else
                    isDigit=false;


            }

            System.out.println(isDigit);






}
```

}

Comment: Test this code I hope you will get your answer.

Comment: Code dumps should not be used as questions or as answers. If you have an answer to share, then please explain it. If you just dump code, your answer will not help anyone in the future.